# memory leak using cJson ESP32

Tags: esp32, cjson

Please could someone help me to identify why there is a memory leak using cJson I could not find the problem. whenever I do an authentication the live memory decreases.
The json is created only at that point, I have already changed the control logic but in any case it always ends up leaking memory

```
esp_err_t loginWS(httpd_req_t *request) {
    JwtService jwtService;
    AutenticationModel autenticationModel;
    AutenticationService autenticationService;

    autenticationModel = autenticationService.loadRegister();

    cJSON *jsonWs;
    cJSON *params;

    std::string token = "";
    std::string msg = "";
    std::string body = "";
    std::string login = "";
    std::string password = "";
    bool error;

    body = _getBody(request); //json received

    jsonWs = cJSON_Parse(body.c_str());

    login = cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonWs, "_login")->valuestring;
    password = cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonWs, "_password")->valuestring;

    if (login == autenticacaoModel.getLogin() && senha == autenticacaoModel.getPassword()) {
        token = jwtService.criarJwt();
        msg = "";
        error = false;
    } else {
        token = "";
        msg = "Login or password invalid";
        error = true;
    }

    cJSON_AddItemToObject(jsonWs = cJSON_CreateObject(), "token", params = cJSON_CreateObject());
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(params, "token", cJSON_CreateString(token.c_str()));

    cJSON_AddItemToObject(jsonWs, "message", params = cJSON_CreateObject());
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(params, "error", cJSON_CreateBool(erro));
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(params, "msg", cJSON_CreateString(mensagem.c_str()));

    const char *texto = cJSON_Print(jsonWs);
    cJSON_Delete(jsonWs);

    httpd_resp_set_hdr(request, "Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpd_resp_sendstr(request, texto);

    free((void *)texto);

    return ESP_OK;
}
```

Comment: Habbit of using  the same variable for different purposes does not pay well - You forgot to call ```cJSON_Delete(jsonWs);``` prior ```jsonWs = cJSON_CreateObject()```. you have a dangling pointer after ```jsonWs = cJSON_Parse(body.c_str());```.

Comment: Pls tag your programming language

Comment: Post the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Seems like you are using `jsonWs` for both parsing and creating the json. Object created using `jsonWs = cJSON_Parse` is reused without deleting `jsonWs = cJSON_CreateObject()`. This may be a problem!